# Does $e^{\ln(x^2)/\log(x)} = e^{x\ln(10)}$

Tags: logarithms

So this is the equation:
$y=|e^{(\ln(x^2)/\log(x)}|$

We can convert log(x) to base e with the change of base rule:
$\log(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$

Then the expression $(\ln(x^2)/\log(x))$ equals $\frac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)/\ln(10)}$, which is equal to
\begin{align} 
\ln(x^2) \cdot \frac{\ln(10)}{\ln(x)} &= 2\ln(x) \cdot \frac{\ln(10)}{\ln(x)}\\
&= 2\ln(10)
\end{align}
So $e^{\ln(x^2)/\log(x)} = e^{2\ln(10)}$.

If you graph the former equation in the question is equals $y=100$, but when you graph the latter, you get some logarithmic curve.

**EDIT**

I figured the problem out now, in the 3rd line, I set $\ln(x^2)$ to $x\ln(x)$ as opposed to $2\ln(x)$

Comment: When is $e^x$ negative? Why have $||$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln x^2 = 2 \ln x$$

Compare $e^{\ln x^2}$ with $e^{2 \ln x}$ if it's not clear.

Comment: OH I see my mistake now! Let me fix it.